# Javascript (ES6) Date to String format

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In Javascript I have `Date` object which I need to convert to string of format `dd.mm.yyyy` and `dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss`. How do I format the Date in Javascript?

Comment: Here's a good tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Comment: There is also [`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a German locale format, so you can use [`Date.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) and [`Date.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) with a German locale setting (`de-DE`):

```js
const date = new Date();

const dateString = date.toLocaleDateString('de-DE');
const timeString = date.toLocaleTimeString('de-DE');

const string = `${dateString} ${timeString}`;

console.log(string);
```

Comment: This is a fantastic solution, just one thing that could give a problem: maybe the month should be displayed as 05 instead of 5.

Comment: @enf0rcer Can be changed by passing the correct `options` to the method. It's all in the documentation I linked in my question. The corresponding option for this case would be `month: "2-digit"`.

Comment: awesome, I just tested it and I think I will be using this a lot as well in the future. I always thought this was not possible using the Date object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use momentjs library for your requirement.

```
constructor(  ) { 
  let now = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  let now2 = moment().format("DD.MM.YYYY");
     this.format1 = now;
     this.format2 = now2;
     console.log(now);

    this.date = moment(this.format1, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/momentjs-format-date?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can use methods of [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object for build your date string:

```
const now = new Date();

const formattedDate = now.getDate() + "." + ('0' + (now.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "." + now.getFullYear();

const formattedDateTime = formattedDate + " " + now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();

console.log(formattedDate); // 28.05.2019

console.log(formattedDateTime); // 28.05.2019 13:19:43
```